# Angular Router still displays HomeComponent on Navigation and not only ChildComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I started learning Angular recently, I'm trying to make a github search app with the github api but I have some problems with routing and passing data. I want the user to go to a page like /user/userID when he/she clicks on view profile button. I have four components including home, list, 404 and app component. When I click the button url changes and list component renders but main page stays there. I want the user to see only the content in the child component. I am solving this problem with "exact" on React but I don't know how to do it in Angular. Also when I try to send data to the list component with the Input(), the list component also appears on the main page. I add screenshots and codes to make it more descriptive.

Home page : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGsPJ.png

user/userID page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmGBl.png

app.component.html :

```
  <ng-template [ngIf]="profile !== '' && user" style=" border: 5px solid black;padding: 2em;">
    <img [src]="user.avatar_url" alt="" style="width: auto; height: 100px;">
    <p>Username: {{user.login}}</p>
    <p>Location: {{user.location}}</p>
    <p>E-mail: {{user.email}}</p>
    <p>Blog Link: {{user.blog}}</p>
    <p>Member Since: {{user.created_at}}</p>
    <button href="#" [routerLink]="['/', user.login.toLowerCase(), user.id ]" style="padding: .5em;">View Profile</button>
  </ng-template>

<div>
  <app-list [data]="user"></app-list>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  user: any;
  profile: any;
  constructor(private userData: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  findProfile() {
    this.userData.updateProfile(this.profile);
    this.userData.getUser().subscribe((result) => {
      console.warn(result);
      this.user = result;
    });
  }

  title = 'my-app';
}
```

list.component.html:

`<h1>list component</h1>`

list.component.ts:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpService } from '../http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss'],
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
  userID: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      params => this.userID = params['userID']
    );
  }

}
```

home.component.html:

`<h1>home component!</h1>`

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: ':user/:userID', component: ListComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try changing this

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
```

to this:

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch:'full'},
{ path: 'list/:user/:userID', component: ListComponent },
```

and this:

```
[routerLink]="['/', user.login.toLowerCase(), user.id ]"
```

to:

```
[routerLink]="['/list', user.login.toLowerCase(), user.id ]"
```

The issue is that `HomeComponent` renders because the router still recognize it as a valid route for the path you are navigation to. The path (without query params) is still empty. Changing the navigation to `'/list'` path should solve things out.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but when I go list/:user/:userID github profile stays there, but when I refresh the page it's gone. How can I solve this?

Comment: It's in the app component, should I move to the home component?

Comment: Yes, correct. Any template in App component will still be rendered. AppComponent should be a very narrow Component.